# How to keep receiving Bluetooth data after opening a web page under iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, background, focus

I have a working iOS / Swift app that reads data pushed from a Bluetooth scanner in didUpdateValueFor() and posts it to a web page. I'm using UIApplication.shared.openURL() to post to the page and it works fine.  However, once the page is opened the app stops receiving reads until it gains focus again.  I want to be able to keep scanning and posting to the page while the page is displayed and the app is in the background. Is there a way to keep Bluetooth messages going to the app even when it doesn't have focus?

Comment: You shouldn't use openURL since there is no way you can stream data over that connection. Your app needs to open a connection to the web server directly using a network socket.

Comment: I want the page to be displayed in a browser so the user can interact with it and the posted data.  Its a simple URL, something like "https://foo.com?data=1234".  I have an Android version of the app that works fine where it repeatably opens the page in the same tab.  I fire up the browser in a separate thread under Android though.  Not sure if that will work under iOS as Apple has tight control over the UI.

Comment: Once you have left your app and opened safari then you can't send any more data. You can receive Bluetooth data in the background but you can't call `openURL` again, since you can only do that when your app is in the foreground and you can't send any more data to the web page since Safari owns the network connection, not your app. You could use a `WKWebView` in your app rather than launching Safari

Comment: ugh.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: So I would have to stream the page and have the app render it.  The app would have to simulate a browser.

Comment: Yes, as I said, WKWebView makes that pretty simple.

Comment: I'll check out WKWebView but if I can receive Bluetooth data in the background can I force my app to the foreground on a read then call openURL?

Comment: No, only the user can return an app to the foreground.

Comment: @Paulw.11  WKWebView worked perfectly and its a much better solution than opening a browser.  Thanks for the idea...ed